# Can I control the output format of an aggregate query?

Tags: mongodb

I'm curious about my options to control the format of aggregate query results.

Below is the result set I'm talking about:

I'd like for `month` and `year` to be on the same level as `average` and `count`. I'd also like for `_id` to go away.

Is that possible?

If not, I can post-process the data, but I wanted to make sure there wasn't anything I was missing first.

```
[
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "month" : 10,
                "year" : 2014
            },
            "average" : 84.2586640583996598,
            "count" : 20959.0000000000000000
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "month" : 11,
                "year" : 2014
            },
            "average" : 96.9326915103888638,
            "count" : 20743.0000000000000000
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1.0000000000000000
}
]
```

... and here's the query to generate those results:

```
db.mycollection.aggregate(
    [
      { 
          $match: { 
              mydate: { 
                  $gte: new Date(Date.UTC(2014, 10, 1)),
                  $lt: new Date(Date.UTC(2014, 12, 1)),
              } 
          } 
      },
      {
        $group : {
           _id : { month: { $month: "$mydate" }, year: { $year: "$mydate" } },
           average: { $avg: "$mynumericfield" },
           count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
      }

   ]
 )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able *rename* fields within the `$project` operation and it's also possible to remove fields from output within `$project`.

(don't know if formatted correctly, just to show the way):

```
db.mycollection.aggregate(
[
  { 
      $match: { 
          mydate: { 
              $gte: new Date(Date.UTC(2014, 10, 1)),
              $lt: new Date(Date.UTC(2014, 12, 1)),
          } 
      } 
  },
  {
    $group : {
       _id : { month: { $month: "$mydate" }, year: { $year: "$mydate" } },
       average: { $avg: "$mynumericfield" },
       count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    $project : {
      _id : 0,
      month : "$_id.month",
      year : "$_id.year",
      average : 1,
      count : 1
    }
  }

  ]
 )
```

Comment: When I try to add month and year to `$group`, mongo gives me the error: `exception: unknown group operator '$month'`

Comment: I updated my answer, you should be able to kinda *rename* fields within the `$project` operation.

Comment: Confirmed, that + adding `average:1,count:1` to the `$project` gives me what I needed. Thanks!